# Python speech recognition and deepspeech

Tags: python-3.x, speech-recognition, offline, mozilla-deepspeech

I'm trying to develop an offline voice assistant using python. I want to use speech recognition module by streaming using microphone and deepspeech. I didn't find something similar like this in the internet. How to do this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

well

Create a Google cloud account.
create a project in Google Cloud. ...
Type “Cloud Speech API” on the project search page
In the API page, click on the “Credentials” section and then click on “Create Credentials”.

This steps let you make your own voice assistant using Python and

```
      but for the offline functionality implementation
```

You can implement google credentials code which let's you use your command for perform specific task. Edit by your choice and system environment

Like we give command to make call , setup timer in our Mobile.

Comment: Google Cloud works only online, but the question says offline voice assistant. I would rather look at projects like https://jasperproject.github.io/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).